# htaccess HTTPS redirect always redirecting to index

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a Laravel application and an `.htaccess` file to redirect all requests to HTTPS. However, the problem is, currently it always redirects to index.php instead of the correct route.

For example:

http://example.com/users/teams

should redirect to:

https://example.com/users/teams

but instead it redirects to:

https://example.com/index.php

This is my current `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

I've been trying to toy around with it and searching for answers but it's not helping.

There is no middleware or anything in Laravel set up to handle HTTPS redirects so there couldn't be any conflict there.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the index.php default path redirection code:-

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

just place this code in your .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Place https redirect before rewriting to index:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```